# Instagram threaded comments

Tags: comments, instagram, instagram-api

as some of you may know, Instagram announced the new threaded comments feature last month: https://instagram-press.com/blog/2017/08/15/keep-the-conversation-going-with-comment-threads/

My question regarding this is: how to address this via API? Is it already possible to date or will it be made possible in the future [@ all Instagram Developers reading this :) ]?

Thank you very much, 
X22

Comment: Hey there, did you find a way yet :p?

Comment: Yes, it well be possible with the new graph api.